# Need help pulling DX out of the stack and putting the value on a 32 bit OFFSET of a signed DWORD

Tags: assembly, x86

Hi everyone I am new to x86 architecture for assembly as well as working on the stack. What I want to do is add the two operand word values together to get 26 and to change the dest dword into
this. I am not too comfortable with working with the stack so my work is a bit of a jumble.My assignment does not allow global variables hence the pushing of both operands. What I had tried to do was dereference both operands and put them onto dx for later. I wanted to in the second procedure get dx wherever it is on the stack and movsx it to the eax(which should go to dest) but neither my dest or operands will show the correct value and will crash the program. Right now I am using dx directly but need it on stack instead.

```
.data
operand1   WORD    46
operand2   WORD    -20
dest       DWORD   0

.code

main PROC

    push   operand1                            ;14
    push   operand2                            ;12
    push   OFFSET dest                         ;8
    call   compute

exit
main ENDP

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
;Compute
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
compute PROC

    mov dx, [ebp + 12]
    add dx, [ebp + 14]
    push dx
    mov eax, [ebp + 8]
    call decoy

     ret
compute ENDP

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------
;Decoy
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------


decoy PROC
    push ebp
    mov ebp,esp

                                                            ;[] dereference
    mov eax,[ebp + 6]                                          ;contains OFFSET
    mov [ebx], eax    
    mov esp,ebp

    ;;Find DX on register and mov that onto eax

    movsx eax, dx




    call   WriteInt
   
   pop ebp
    
decoy ENDP
```

Comment: Your `compute PROC` never sets up EBP as a frame pointer before dereferencing it!  And your main doesn't either, so you're just accessing memory relative to some left-over value.  You're only doing it in `decoy`.

Comment: Also, in 32-bit mode, you generally don't want to use 16-bit push (of `dx` for example); that would misalign the stack pointer.  Just do `push edx` to pad the stack arg to a 4-byte slot, even if you only want to be working with 16-bit integers.  (This is what standard 32-bit calling conventions do for stack args; if you're going to use a custom one, it would be even better to just pass args in registers.)

Comment: would it be wiser to move all the stuff with dx and eax to decoy instead of compute to save space?

Comment: If you cared about optimizing at all (especially for total code size), you'd just inline everything into the caller and remove the helper functions.  They're called once each, so the work of passing and retrieving args, and the actual `call` instructions, is pure overhead vs. `mov eax, dword ptr [operand1]` / `add eax, dword ptr [operand2]` / `cwde` (sign-extend AX -> EAX, discarding the old high 16 bits) / `call WriteInt`.  (That overreads 2 bytes past the end of `operand2`, but one `cwde` is 1 byte, vs. two operand-size prefixes on mov word / add word.  But that's excessive code-golfing :P)

Comment: I don't know what artificial requirements your assignment has, like why you need two functions at all and if so what restrictions there are on splitting up the work between them.  Or if there's any reason to be passing a pointer to store the result instead of just returning a value in EAX like a normal function, for the caller to use as they wish.  (It's also weird that you're passing a pointer to a global variable when your assignment said no globals.  `main` could reserve space on its stack and `lea ecx, [esp + 4]` or whatever as an output pointer arg.)